# Create javascript script tag and bind to knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to generate knockout templates dynamically and then binding them. As a poc I wrote the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/knockout-3.1.0.debug.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
    <button onclick="bind()">Bind</button>
</body>
<script>
    function start() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.id = "summary";
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('data-bind', 'text: title');

        script.appendChild(div);

        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    var viewModel = {
        articles: [{
            id: 1,
            title: "Article One",
            content: "Content for article one."
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Article Two",
            content: "Content for article two."
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: "Article Three",
            content: "Content for article three."
        }
        ]
    };

    function bind() {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Can anyone shed any light on why the code does not display the bound template?

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stick the generated DIV inside another element with a foreach binding on the articles property, or bind to a specific article like ko.applyBindings(viewModel.articles[0]).

Follow up: I created a fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tuando/4s4Me/), but it appears that it Knockout won't execute bindings inside a script tag. See my comment where I note that it works if you were to use a DIV, but not a script tag.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');  // works if you change this to a div tag
```

Comment: Thanks very much, script tags might only be evaluated once, so dynamically adding them might get ignored (security feature??)

Comment: Turns out that if I set the innerhtml of the script tag to the content I require, all works as expected. No idea why though.